# Filling in column based on column values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a set of values in a column as follows:

```
1
1

3
3

12
12

43
43




94
94


88
88
```

The spacing is arbitrary but there are always two of each value. What I'd like to do is fill in the blanks with the number above up until the next number occurs. The result would look like this:

```
1
1
1
3
3
3
12
12
12
43
43
43
43
43
43
94
94
94
94
88
88
```

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the column with the values
2. Go to: "find and select" - "special"; select "blanks" and press "ok"
3. type `=` then press the UP ARROW
4. press CTRL + ENTER

Now you have it, all new values are formulas, if you want just constant values then select again your column, copy it, a paste only values to the same place.

Comment: That sounds like it would work well, but one issue is that blank cells are not showing up as such.

Comment: @114 - what do you mean by "not showing up as such"?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column B in B1=A1, in B2 =IF(A2="",B1,A2) and drag it down till last value of column A, after copy all column B and use paste special Values in a new column C for example you will have the new Data and you can delete the helper columns A and B